# Append a new row to the end of sheets using Gspread

Tags: gspread

I have this code, I need to append the values to the columns in my google sheet and the values should be added at the end of the sheet in a new row without deleting existing datas

```
all_values = worksheet.get_all_values()
row_count = len(all_values)
sheet_range = "'{}'!{row}:{row}".format(worksheet.title, row=row_count+1+insert_count)

values = {
  "Name": "Ford",
  "Age": "34",
  "Color": 'Blue'
}
worksheet.append_row(sheet_range, values)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out, it's actually quite simple.

```
body=[0, 4, 9,7,5] #the values should be a list

worksheet.append_row(body, table_range="A1:E1") 

#table_range should be range of columns in the sheet, example from A1 to E1 (A1:E1)
other parameters are optional. 

this will append the values in body to the last row in the sheet and it will not overwrite existing data.
```

Answer (score 0):

have to tried to resize the sheet to the number of rows that are actualy present ? :

```
sheet.resize(1)
```

Comment: thanks. 
i already found a fix and it is working now.